# When running a job to update a table, my table doesn't seem to drop when I'm trying to repopulate it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

My question is about why my table didn't seem to drop when I updated the job to insert more values.

I had to add two extra columns (latitude & longitude) to my table. I updated my job to look like the following:

```
    BEGIN TRAN T2;

    IF (OBJECT_ID('Warehouse.dbo.table') IS NOT NULL)
      DROP TABLE Warehouse.dbo.table;

    CREATE TABLE Warehouse.dbo.table
    ( id nvarchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
      address1 varchar(max),
      address2 varchar(max),
      city varchar(60),
      state varchar(30),
      country varchar(45),
      zip varchar(30),
      latitude FLOAT,
      longitude FLOAT
    );

    INSERT INTO Warehouse.dbo.table

    SELECT DISTINCT
      long_id AS id,
      address1 AS address1,
      adress2 AS address2,
      city AS city,
      state AS state,
      country AS country,
      zip AS zip,
      latitude AS latitude,
      longitude AS longitude
    FROM Warehouse.dbo.other_table

    COMMIT TRAN T2;
```

It has unions etc. but the code runs. When I tried to run the job, I would get the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Now I added two columns but I drop the table and recreate it, so I am unsure of why the table did not seem to drop. I had to manually run

```
 DROP TABLE Warehouse.dbo.table;
```

and THEN run my job again for it to update with the two new columns.

Does anybody have an explanation? Is there a way to make sure the drop works so I don't have to manually drop it?

Thank you!

Comment: try to remove the brackats  if object_id('warehouse.dbo.table') is not null drop

Comment: @Alexandra Goldina, this script didn't present any issues when I recreated the tables.  The only thing I'm not sure of are the contents and/or the columns of _dbo.other_table_.

Comment: you got a compilation error after your code change.  It never executed the `drop`, it kept the previous table w/o your two new fields.  Your updated code wouldn't compile until the schema changed.

Comment: @Beth, how do I change the schema? The drop is the first thing that shows up in the code.

Comment: whenever your schema needs to change, which shouldn't be often, you just need to drop the table manually.  Then you can make your change to your SSIS code referencing the new columns.

Comment: Ah, understood. Thank you so much Beth!

Comment: I think you can alternately break the drop out into it's own transaction and the compiler handles it better. I run into this every now and then and it's rather annoying.

Comment: How about using `GO` statement in next line after the drop table statement and then carry on with rest of the steps?

Comment: You need [ ] brackets around table. Table is an function it self and it doesnt know how to works when you havent put it into brackets. Put [ ] around all table except in your OBJECT_ID statement

Comment: @AnthonyHancock, my concern is if it runs and then re-populating fails, I'm left with an empty table.

I'll give the GO a try. We're restructuring data into a new database and so changes are coming up quite often, it's the little annoyances that build up!

Comment: @Sasha, if you are concerned about losing the data you could do a SELECT * INTO to make a temporary backup, then drop that at the end of the next transaction if it succeeds, if it doesn't repopulate then have a catch statement that moves all the data back into the original table